# TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. when using the deepvog module

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am having a problem with trying to get the DeepVOG model up and running.I created a script with the following code:

```
import deepvog
import matplotlib
from  deepvog.model.DeepVOG_model import load_DeepVOG
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

# Camera specsls
focal_length = 6
sensor_size =  [3.6, 1.8]
# Video shape
video_shape = [400, 640]
# Model initialization
model = load_DeepVOG()
```

and when I run it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tzikos/DeepVOG/deepvog/gaze_estimator.py", line 13, in <module>
    model = load_DeepVOG()
  File "/home/tzikos/anaconda3/envs/deepvog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepvog/model/DeepVOG_model.py", line 120, in load_DeepVOG
    model = DeepVOG_net(input_shape = (240, 320, 3), filter_size= (10,10))
  File "/home/tzikos/anaconda3/envs/deepvog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepvog/model/DeepVOG_model.py", line 101, in DeepVOG_net
    X_out = decoding_block(X = X_out, X_jump = X_jump4, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 256, 
  File "/home/tzikos/anaconda3/envs/deepvog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepvog/model/DeepVOG_model.py", line 43, in decoding_block
    if tf.math.reduce_all(tf.equal(tf.convert_to_tensor(X_jump),tf.keras.backend.zeros_like(X_jump))):
  File "/home/tzikos/anaconda3/envs/deepvog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 221, in __len__
    raise TypeError('Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not '
TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly.
```

I have searched far and wide in google but nothing comes back with a result.I do not know why this thing locks in this particular line. For more details, the code invoked is:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense, Activation, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model

def encoding_block(X, filter_size, filters_num, layer_num, block_type, stage, s = 1, X_skip=0):
    
    # defining name basis
    conv_name_base = 'conv_' + block_type + str(stage) + '_'
    bn_name_base = 'bn_' + block_type + str(stage)  + '_'
    
    
    for i in np.arange(layer_num)+1:
        # First component of main path 
        X = Conv2D(filters_num, filter_size , strides = (s,s), padding = 'same', name = conv_name_base + 'main_' + str(i), kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X)
        X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + 'main_' + str(i))(X)
        if i != layer_num:
            X = Activation('relu')(X)


    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    # Down sampling layer
    X_downed = Conv2D(filters_num*2, (2, 2), strides = (2,2), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + 'down', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X)
    X_downed = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + 'down')(X_downed)
    X_downed = Activation('relu')(X_downed)
    return X, X_downed

def decoding_block(X, filter_size, filters_num, layer_num, block_type, stage, s = 1, X_jump = np.zeros((1)), up_sampling = True):
    
    # defining name basis
    conv_name_base = 'conv_' + block_type + str(stage) + '_'
    bn_name_base = 'bn_' + block_type + str(stage)  + '_'
    

    # Joining X_jump from encoding side with X_uped
    print(1)
    if tf.math.reduce_all(tf.equal(tf.convert_to_tensor(X_jump),tf.keras.backend.zeros_like(X_jump))):
        print("1a")
        X_joined_input = X
    else:
        print("1b")
        X_joined_input = Concatenate(axis = 3)([X,X_jump])
    print(2)

    ##### MAIN PATH #####
    for i in np.arange(layer_num)+1:
        # First component of main path 
        X_joined_input = Conv2D(filters_num, filter_size , strides = (s,s), padding = 'same',
                                name = conv_name_base + 'main_' + str(i), kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X_joined_input)
        X_joined_input = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + 'main_' + str(i))(X_joined_input)
        if i != layer_num:
            X_joined_input = Activation('relu')(X_joined_input)
    print(3)

    X_joined_input = Activation('relu')(X_joined_input)
    
    # Up-sampling layer. At the output layer, up-sampling is disabled and replaced by other stuffs manually
    if up_sampling == True:
        X_uped = Conv2DTranspose(filters_num, (2, 2), strides = (2,2), padding = 'valid',
                                 name = conv_name_base + 'up', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X_joined_input)
        X_uped = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + 'up')(X_uped)
        X_uped = Activation('relu')(X_uped)
        print(4)
        return X_uped
    else:
        print(4)
        return X_joined_input
    

# FullVnet
# Output layers have 3 channels. The first two channels represent two one-hot vectors (pupil and non-pupil)
# The third layer contains all zeros in all cases (trivial)
def DeepVOG_net(input_shape = (240, 320, 3), filter_size= (3,3)):
    
    X_input = Input(input_shape)
    
    Nh, Nw = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
    
    # Encoding Stream
    X_jump1, X_out = encoding_block(X = X_input, X_skip = 0, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 16,
                                      layer_num= 1, block_type = "down", stage = 1, s = 1)
    X_jump2, X_out = encoding_block(X = X_out, X_skip = X_out, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 32,
                                      layer_num= 1, block_type = "down", stage = 2, s = 1)
    X_jump3, X_out = encoding_block(X = X_out, X_skip = X_out, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 64,
                                      layer_num= 1, block_type = "down", stage = 3, s = 1)
    X_jump4, X_out = encoding_block(X = X_out, X_skip = X_out, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 128,
                                      layer_num= 1, block_type = "down", stage = 4, s = 1)
    
    # Decoding Stream
    print("dec0")
    print(type(X_jump4))
    X_out = decoding_block(X = X_out, X_jump = 0, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 256, 
                                 layer_num= 1, block_type = "up", stage = 1, s = 1)
    print("dec1")
    X_out = decoding_block(X = X_out, X_jump = X_jump4, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 256, 
                                 layer_num= 1, block_type = "up", stage = 2, s = 1)
    print("dec2")
    X_out = decoding_block(X = X_out, X_jump = X_jump3, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 128, 
                                 layer_num= 1, block_type = "up", stage = 3, s = 1)
    X_out = decoding_block(X = X_out, X_jump = X_jump2, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 64, 
                                 layer_num= 1, block_type = "up", stage = 4, s = 1)
    X_out = decoding_block(X = X_out, X_jump = X_jump1, filter_size= filter_size, filters_num= 32, 
                                 layer_num= 1, block_type = "up", stage = 5, s = 1, up_sampling = False)
    # Output layer operations
    X_out = Conv2D(filters = 3, kernel_size = (1,1) , strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid',
                   name = "conv_out", kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X_out)
    X_out = Activation("softmax")(X_out)
    model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = X_out, name='Pupil')
    
    return model

def load_DeepVOG():
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    model = DeepVOG_net(input_shape = (240, 320, 3), filter_size= (10,10))
    model.load_weights(os.path.join(base_dir, "DeepVOG_weights.h5"))
    return model
```

Why does the above logical operation fail?